# Why is 0 larger than 0 (according to the vscode debugger)?

Tags: python, math, vscode-debugger

On line 7 there is a variable x which is equal to 0. When I run the program, it should not advance to the next indent if x is not greater than 0. But for some reason it does.

[image: 0 > 0 is True]

What is going on?

```
class MyProblem():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    def recursive(self):
        self.x -= 1
        if self.x > 0:
            self.recursive()

p = MyProblem()
p.recursive()
```

Comment: I can't see your image. But printing `x` in the conditional block never prints `0`

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan That depends on where you put the print in the conditional block.  Try putting it *after* self.recursive()   My bet is the breakpoint has already returned from self.recursive() and hasn't *quite* exited the function yet.  I could reproduce the state on a different IDE by single-stepping.

Comment: Putting `print(self.x)` both before and after the `self.recursive()` gave me  `4` `3` `2` `1` `0` `0` `0` `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the debugger highlight the line `self.recursive()` when `self.x` is 0 is because it is popping the call stack: recall, you entered this recursive function when `x` was 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Once `x` reaches 0, you see the debugger **leaving** the recursive function for 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, which is why stepping on that line leaves you at the same line.